# Saving https page so that you can prove origin

Tags: c#, https, cryptography, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

The way I understand how this stuff works, when you download page from web server via https, the info received should contain information which can authenticate server. I want to save this information, so that later I can prove that the page has been downloaded from someone who knows private key that matches server's public key.

How do I do this?

Comment: HTTPS and SSL has nothing to do with the contents. Specifically, there is nothing it can give you to show that you really did download this very data from this source. You would have to do packet capture, capture the key exchange (and, provided that does not have perfect secrecy) you can then decrypt it if and only if you yourself have the server's private key.

Comment: What you're looking for is cryptographic signing -> if you need to prove the source of origin of some data, that source has to sign it. Then you can use the PUBLIC key of that entity to verify that they have, indeed, signed it. But that requires a server-side implementation, and it can't really be incorporated into the basic HTML pages because the browsers don't really know how to deal with signed data and interpret it as HTML.(AFAIC)

Comment: @zaitsman so the data transferred with SSL is encrypted using my own public key and is in no way signed by the sender? How does the software know than that the data comes from the right origin and has not been tempered with?

Comment: it doesn't know that at all :) When you are using SSL, the data in the packets is actually encrypted with a session key negotiated between the client and the server. Since the key only exists on both ends of the session, if EC or perfect secrecy was used, it is impractical in today's world to bruteforce or guess that key. This is why data is not tampered with - it couldn't be decrypted if it was.

The client has no idea whether the data originated at a source; but it can only decrypt what was encrypted with the session key.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: There is an authentication tag over the data, but that message authentication tag is only used for the transport security and is discarded once the TLS message has been received. It is created with a key that is specific to the session. And they are created with the temporary DH keys. The only way to verify those is with the public key of the server; not the most practical thing to do, in other words.